# Django queryset filter - why is an object meeting all criteria in the filter not included in result set?

Tags: python, django, orm

My web app is not sending reminders to certain users who should get them. In trying to debug, the following example in a python shell has me pretty confused. Is there anything I'm missing, or doing wrong in the filter?

If there's nothing obviously wrong, how can I debug this issue?

```
>>> now = timezone.now()
>>> an_hour_ago = now - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
>>> suz = User.objects.get(email="redacted")
>>> suz.reminded
False
>>> suz.wait_until <= now
True
>>> suz.wait_until >= an_hour_ago
True
>>> suz.is_active
True
>>> remindable = User.objects.filter(is_active=True,
...                                  reminded=False,
...                                  wait_until__gte=an_hour_ago,
...                                  wait_until__lte=now)
>>> suz in remindable
False
```

**Edit**: adding in my user model.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    wait_until = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    # etc.
```

**Edit 2**: Some additional context:

I have a view in which a user completes a task. After they complete the task, `wait_until` is set to a random time, based on a range set in a Configuration object. Pertinent code from that view:

```
config = Configuration.objects.first()
min_minutes = config.min_minutes_between_tasks
max_minutes = config.max_minutes_between_tasks
when = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=randint(min_minutes,
                                                max_minutes+1))
user.wait_until = when
user.alerted = False
user.save()
```

**Edit 3**: I'm not sure what happened, but I'm probably just an idiot.

I restarted my python shell and `suz` is now returning correctly in `remindable` as expected. I suspect I had changed one of the attributes above and didn't run `suz.save()`. That would certainly explain it. ORMs... remember to `save()` your in-memory objects, kids!

Comment: What is `wait_until` and how/when is it defined?

Comment: Good question - it's a `DateTimeField`. I added a partial representation of my `User` model.

Comment: How/when is `wait_until` generated?

Comment: It's created and then updated each time the user completes a task, which they are only allowed to do _after_ `wait_until`. I added the pertinent code from my view above.

Comment: Just in case `suz in remindable` doesn't do what you think it does, try `User.objects.get(email="redacted", is_active=True, ...)` and see what it does.

Comment: So... I think I just did something dumb like `suz.reminded=False` and never ran `suz.save()`. That would explain everything. Is it wrong that I kind of want to downvote my own question?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, add as such as information to the question as possible.
It is hard to see the problem when there is not enough background.
I still don't know what is this `now`:

```
when = now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=randint(min_minutes,
                                                max_minutes+1))
```

And what is `user.alerted`? If it doesn't matter, don't show it.

When debugging:

1. make sure all the things you filter by were used to get the
   object you are looking for (i.e. what @Alex Hall suggested, add
   `email`)
2. If you can make sure all the different times compared
   are the same type, and timezone
3. Try removing filter criteria one
   by one, see which one may be the issue
4. Print the `QuerySet` produced by the filter- what are the objects that were included, vs the ones that were not?
5. What is the database you are using? It may be storing the time differently when saved

Comment: If you had done #3 from the list, you would have caught it.
Can you accept the answer?